# Java parsing one JSON field to two Java fields without setters

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am using sprintboot and I have a model like:

```java
public class Source {

    # I have 10 annotation here validator
    # @NotNull @Deserializer and other
    public String raw_data;

    # I have 10 annotation here validator
    # @NotNull @Deserializer and other
    public String fix_data;  

    # i have more than 100+ other field
}
```

I want to parse this data into a fixed version, but still retain the original raw version.

```json
{"data":"somedata"}
```

The data can't start with a number.

- `"abc"` would be valid
- `"1abc"` would be invalid

So I want my java class to get parsed as:

```java
public class Source {
    public String raw_data = "1abc";
    public String fix_data = "abc";
}
```

I tried to use `@JsonAlias` but it didn't work. I also tried to use `@JsonProperty` but I got `error: Multiple fields representing property`.

How can I decode the json value into two fields?

Comment: Your question needs clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i do update it with change

Comment: what do you mean by this? _`# I have 10 annotation here validator`_

Comment: i have NotNull Deserializer and lots of other custom my cowork did

Answer (score 0):

Map data -> raw_data and in your method:

```
setRawData(String rawData){
  this.rawData = rawData;
  this.fixedData = rawData.replace("1", ""); // Whatever you do to fix it
}
```

Comment: how i can do without setter?

Comment: Why would you not use the setter?

Comment: i use other @ objects thing and when i use the setter my model not working

Comment: i use different type too like number and class for field

Comment: Your example has 2 strings, no annotations and no clear example

Comment: yes i hvae like 10 annotation by field that why i no put them

Answer (score 0):

You could use @JsonCreator applied to the constructor to deserialize the mentioned JSON structure.

```java
public class Source {

    public String rawData;
    public String fixdata;

    @JsonCreator
    public Source(@JsonProperty("data") String data) {
        this.rawData = data;
        this.fixData = data.replaceAll("^(\\d+)", ""); // removing digits at the start
    }
}
```

**Test**

```java
String json = "{\"data\":\"1abc\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Source src = mapper.readValue(json, Source.class);
System.out.printf("raw: '%s', input: '%s'%n", src.rawData, src.fixData);
```

Output:

```
raw: '1abc', input: 'abc'
```

Comment: What if I have mlutiple values?

Comment: Which multiple values?

Comment: So you just add other values to the constructor and set them there.

Comment: i have 1 model with 100+ properties

Comment: Why did not post it in the question then?  It seems like an important detail

Comment: And if you have 100+ properties why you can't have setters then?

Comment: It would be much simpler to add @JsonProperty to the setter which will handle this specific pair of fields

Comment: i dont want to create 100+ setters and 100+ getter

Comment: 1. Nowadays, setters and getters are generated automatically in any good IDE. 2. It is possible to use Lombok project to generate boilerplate setters for you using annotations `@Getter` `@Setter` or `@Data`, so you'll just have to implement only relevant setters.

Comment: By the way you claimed that _all other fields are null_.  But what do you expect if you provide a JSON with a single `"data"` field defined?

Comment: You posted a question with a narrow context.  You got a working "copy-paste-ready" answer to that question within the initial context.  And instead of saying "thanks" you start remembering details of your actual context and may be even realizing that your actual problem is totally different.  Like, having 100+ properties in a model is rather a big smell.